# dojo.xhrPost passing special characters incorrectly to server

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, dojo

We discovered an error with unix based filenames getting passed to our windows server through windows based web browsers.  dojo.xhrPost defaults to  ISO-8859-1 character encoding. This would result in the server receiving malformed filenames, where ± would be replaced with Â±.

Whereas there are java based solutions, including filters, that can be added to Tomcat, we wanted to find a way to correct this in our JavaScript instead.

Answer provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to force the xhrPost to pass the correct contentType header information, including the utf-8 charset specifier.

```
dojo.xhrPost{
    url: resURL,
    handleAs: "xml",
    load: callBackResetForm,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    ....
})
```